# arguments in function inside setInterval not changing

Tags: javascript, setinterval, polling

I'm implementing polling using setInterval but I'm running into some issues. I have a function to poll that looks like this

```
const pollMessages = () => {
  if (interval) {
    return false;
  }
  interval = setInterval(callApi, delay);
};
```

I also have a function to clear the interval

```
const stopPolling = () => {
  if (interval) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = null;
  }
};
```

The `callApi` function takes in an argument and makes a request to an endpoint. It looks like this

```
  const callApi = () => {
    Api.get('/new-message', lastMessage)
  }
```

The catch here is every time a request is made, if there are new messages, the lastMessage variable is supposed to be updated but the issue I'm having is that the value doesn't update in the new requests. It continues sending with the old lastMessage. I've tried passing the updated lastMessage as an argument to `callApi` but it doesn't make any difference. I'd want a situation where the lastMessage argument can be changed in some requests while setInterval is running. How do I resolve this?

Comment: show us the expected output vs what you are seeing please, and include the part where you test  lastMessage

Comment: Better to have a live demo which reproduces the issue. Recommend codepen, jsfiddle, jsbin.

Comment: Just because you've cleared an interval, that does not mean that the request that was already sent with no response yet at the time won't come back, because `.get()` itself is asynchronous.

Comment: @StackSlave I'm aware the response is asynchronous but I've been monitoring my network request and logged the value of lastMessage. It doesn't change even when the api returns new messages. it keeps using the old one

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your code correctly, this is because the value of lastMessage is being sent as a parameter, not a reference to the variable itself.

You'll want to create a setter function that you can call with a value to pass in order to change the variable.

For example:

```js
const setLastMessage = (value) => {
  lastMessage = value;
}
```

You'd then pass `setLastMessage` as a parameter and adjust your API functions accordingly.